# Storing imageView in NSDictionary iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, nsdictionary

I'm my application I want to pass an UIImageView to NSDictionary.

Comment: Why?  Not much information here.

Comment: I basically want to know wheather it should be passed as a string or pointer to imageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anImageInstance forKey:@"imageKey"];
```

... will work. Dictionaries are designed precisely to hold objects. They will hold any object without any fuss.